# Unable to Create Lead - Insufficient Privileges

Tags: sharing, leads, insufficient-privileges

I am attempting to allow a profile to create a lead.

**The profile has:**
The lead record type assigned.
The correct page layout assigned.
Create, read, and edit permissions assigned for the lead object. 
All fields on the page layout assigned. 
Field level security confirms all fields on the page layout are visible.

**Sharing settings:**
The lead object is defaulted to private, but within the sharing settings I am sharing leads created by one of my top-level roles and it's sub-ordinates to the same top-level role and it's sub-ordinates. The users being tested are in this role hierarchy.

The primary function is to create the leads through a Visualforce Page and Apex Class and THIS functionality does SUCCESSFULLY result in a lead that the profile can view and edit this lead from the list view.

However, going to the Lead Tab in the console, clicking new lead, and selecting the lead record type results in an insufficient privilege error.

What am I missing?

Clarification:

The VFP page SUCCESSFULLY results in a lead. The default "New Lead" button on the list view, results in Insufficient Privileges.

To clarify further, this is in regards to creating leads, the leads can be viewed once created form the VFP/Apex Class but cannot be created be created through the "New lead" default button.

Comment: Does the lead has a record type? if so make sure in the profile the record type is also added in

Comment: Record type assignment already mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default "New Lead" button results in a page that all users have access to where they can select their record type.

However, after selecting a record type and proceeding, users are taken to a native Visualforce Page called "LeadPage" (can someone confirm that this is native from another classic org?). Once access to this VFP was provided, users could generate leads.

Users were able to create leads from the custom VFP because access was assigned, I was unaware there was a native "LeadPage" VFP that users have to be provided access to after clicking the console default "New Lead" button.